# Exclude a record when concatenating values in column | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to transform a table that looks like this:

```
ID    |  Year  |  Code   | Cond 
---------------------------------
1     |  2020  |    a    | False
1     |  2018  |    b    | False
1     |  2018  |    c    | True
1     |  2017  |    d    | False
2     |  2019  |    e    | False
2     |  2018  |    f    | False
2     |  2017  |    g    | False
3     |  2020  |    h    | False
3     |  2018  |    i    | False
```

to a table with a 'Sequence' column that includes a concatenation of the 'Year' values of all records with the same 'ID', plus the 'Code' of the latest record. The 'Sequence' should NOT include the year of the record that has 'True' in the 'Cond' column though.

So, the final table should look like this:

```
ID    |  Year  |  Code   | Cond  |  Sequence
---------------------------------------------------
1     |  2020  |    a    | False | 2017x2018x2020_a
1     |  2018  |    b    | False | 2016x2018x2020_a
1     |  2017  |    c    | True  | 2016x2018x2020_a
1     |  2016  |    d    | False | 2016x2018x2020_a
2     |  2019  |    e    | False | 2017x2018x2019_e
2     |  2018  |    f    | False | 2017x2018x2019_e
2     |  2017  |    g    | False | 2017x2018x2019_e
3     |  2020  |    h    | False | 2018x2020_h
3     |  2018  |    i    | False | 2018x2020_h
```

Currently, I have this code that does almost everything I have mentioned, but it doesn't exclude the records based on the 'Cond'. This is the part I need to be helped with.

```
df['Sequence'] = (df.astype({'Year': str})
                    .groupby('ID')['Year']
                    .transform(lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1]))
                    .add('_' + df['Code'].astype(str)))
```

Thank you very kindly for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude rows by `Cond` before `groupby`:

```
df1 = (df.join(df.astype({'Year':str})[~df['Cond']]
         .groupby('ID')
         .agg({'Year': lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1]), 'Code':'first'}), 
              on='ID', rsuffix='_'))
df['Sequence'] = df1.pop('Year_') + '_' + df1.pop('Code_')


print (df)
   ID  Year Code   Cond          Sequence
0   1  2020    a  False  2016x2018x2020_a
1   1  2018    b  False  2016x2018x2020_a
2   1  2017    c   True  2016x2018x2020_a
3   1  2016    d  False  2016x2018x2020_a
4   2  2019    e  False  2017x2018x2019_e
5   2  2018    f  False  2017x2018x2019_e
6   2  2017    g  False  2017x2018x2019_e
7   3  2020    h  False       2018x2020_h
8   3  2018    i  False       2018x2020_h
```

If need each code separately:

```
df1 = (df.join(df.astype({'Year':str})[~df['Cond']]
          .groupby('ID')
          .agg({'Year': lambda x: 'x'.join(x[::-1])}), 
              on='ID', rsuffix='_'))
df['Sequence'] = df1.pop('Year_') + '_' + df1['Code']


print (df)
   ID  Year Code   Cond          Sequence
0   1  2020    a  False  2016x2018x2020_a
1   1  2018    b  False  2016x2018x2020_b
2   1  2017    c   True  2016x2018x2020_c
3   1  2016    d  False  2016x2018x2020_d
4   2  2019    e  False  2017x2018x2019_e
5   2  2018    f  False  2017x2018x2019_f
6   2  2017    g  False  2017x2018x2019_g
7   3  2020    h  False       2018x2020_h
8   3  2018    i  False       2018x2020_i
```